# Qty Control in C#

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

pstrjds, From the code you have provided I am trying to implement that code and the msdn link you provided couple of days ago. I am not sure how to put it together but I am see a message that "The variable name '@ID' has already been declared. Variable names must be unique within a query batch or stored procedurce." Do I need to create a stored procedurce? Can I assume I got the ID bit right as well, where you explained number of times?   Thank you.
           enter code here

```
        cs.Open();
        int remainingStock = 0;
        string Query = "SELECT StockA SET QTY = @QTY " + "WHERE ID = @ID;";
           SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(Query, cs);
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@ID", SqlDbType.Int);
            cmd.Parameters["@ID"].Value = 1;
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", Query);
            try
            {
                if (remainingStock == 1)
                {
                    lbqty.Text = "Not enough stocks.";
                }
                else
                {
                    cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE StockA SET QTY = QTY-1   
                    WHERE ID=1";
                    int rowsUpdated = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    remainingStock--;
                    string remaining = "Remaining stocks: " +  
                    remainingStock.ToString();
                    txQty.Text = remaining;
                    lbqty.Text = remaining;
                    DGA.Update(); //this is DataGridView
                }
                Int32 rowsAffected = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                Console.WriteLine("RowsAffected: {0}", rowsAffected);

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
               MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
            cs.Close();

    }
```

Comment: I've merged the two questions.  If you need to clarify, edit your question, don't open a new one.  Thanks.

Comment: You don't need the AddWithValue line, if you want to use AddWithValue then remove the Add("@ID", SqlDbType.Int) and parameters["@ID"].Value = 1 and replace it with AddWithValue("@ID", 1);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After reading your question again, I am more convinced that the comment I posted is actually the problem. You said in your question that your quantity is not going down. If you look at the return value from the line:

```
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

in your else statement I believe you will get a value of 0. This indicates that no records where updated. I believe the problem is exactly related to your query. If you connect to your database with a utility such as LINQPad or the Sql Management studio and run the query you have listed in your code I think you will find it is not updating anything. I highly suspect that your inventory is not being stored in a table called `tblContacts`. Which is why you can't select a quantity from it nor update a quantity in it.

Edit:
Meant to mention this initially and then got sidetracked and forgot to add it. I would put your SqlCommand in a using statement. The SqlCommand object is disposable and so it is good practice to place disposable objects in a using statement or in some sort of try/finally pattern where they can be cleaned up.

Additional edit - restructuring your code:

```
    cs.Open();
    int remainingStock = 0;
    string Query = "SELECT QTY from tblInventory WHERE ID=19";
    using(SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(Query, cs))
    {
        var result = cmd.ExecuteScaler();
        if (result != null)
        {
            string str = result.ToString();
            if (!string.isNullOrWhiteSpace(str))
            {
                // NOTE: It would probably be safer to use int.TryParse here
                remainingStock = Convert.ToInt32(cmd);
            }

            if (remainingStock == 0)
            {
                lbqty.Text = "Not enough stocks.";
            }
            else
            {
                cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE tblInventory SET QTY = QTY-1 WHERE ID=19";
                int rowsUpdated = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                remainingStock--;

                if (remainingStock == 1)
                {
                    lbqty.Text = "Re-order. Remaining stocks: 1";
                }
                else
                {
                    string remaining = "Remaining stocks: " + remainingCount.ToString();
                    txtQty.Text = remaining;
                    lbqty.Text = remaining;
                }
            }
        }
        else
            lbqty.Text = "No stock for contact";
        }

        dgUpdate();
    }
    cs.Close();
```

Comment: Pstrids - Oh I see. I will have a go at this I will let you know asap on how I am getting on. Thank you.

Comment: @user so any update? Did you check whether you were accessing the right table? I am still fairly confident that that is your issue. Especially since you have commented that your stock level isn't being reduced. That is a function of the queries you are running, not the UI update.

Comment: Pstrids - Sorry about the delay and yes I have an update. I only have one table, tblContacts. I am getting the following error...NullReferenceException was unhandled "Object reference not set to an instance of an object." for the line string str = cmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString(); So converting the object to string won't solve the problem either? Any suggestion?

Comment: I updated the code, you need to check the result of the ExecuteScalar. It is coming back as null, that means that the query is returning an empty recordset. This is why your data isn't being updated, there is no related record.

Comment: I am still getting the same error message for the line...string str = result.ToString();

Comment: @user if `result == null` then you shouldn't call the line result.ToString(). You need to do something in the if block. I just put a comment in there, you should return by the end of the statement or set the result to something else. If it is null you will get the exception. That is the point I was trying to make, you are getting a null back because there is no record for the row ID=1. This is also why your update query is not updating any data. Could you save a backup of your database and place a link to it in a comment. I would be happy to take a look and help you further.

Comment: You mean the following...CREATE TABLE tblContacts
(
  ID INT IDENTITY NOT NULL,
  FIRSTNAME VARCHAR (100),
  LASTNAME VARCHAR (100), QTY INT
)

Comment: I was actually looking for the physical database, but this helps. I have mentioned the issue a couple of times now, but will say it again. You have no record in your database for ID=1 (or your code is passing in a different ID), but either way, there is no entry for this ID. You need to adjust your code to handle that situation correctly. I will edit my code above to give you a better starting point.

Comment: I think I am getting there. I have changed WHERE ID = 1 to WHERE ID =@ID. Then I got an error Must declare the scalar variable "@ID". So I looked this up and I saw that I had to use the 'Add Parameter', something like this...cmd.Parameters.Add("@ID", cs); but now I have another error msg...No mapping exists from object type System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection to a known managed provider native type. So I am currently looking this up.

Comment: pstrjds - I have the following error because I have changed to WHERE ID = @ID and added  cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", Query); error...Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value 'SELECT QTY from  WHERE ID=@ID' to data type int. I think the code I have added is right I am unsure over comming this error?

Comment: @user - Check this link on the Parameter usage: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.parameters.aspx

Comment: @user you would need to have the lines: cmd.Parameters.Add("@ID", SqlDbType.Int);  
cmd.Parameters["@ID"].Value = 1;

Comment: @user - Passing your value as a parameter is still not your issue. Your issue is that there is `no record in your database with an ID of 1` and so you are not getting a value back nor are you able to update the database. You need to pass in an ID that matches a row in your database or handle the case of no matching ID (see my code above, I edited to handle this case specifically). The issue is not really your C# code, the issue is that you are not checking the return values from the database commands and handling the case of the rows not being there.

Comment: @user Can you run this query in sql management console and post the results in your question?: `SELECT * FROM tblContacts`

Comment: Please bear with me. I still need to implement the cmd.Parameters.Add("@ID", SqlDbType.Int); and cmd.Parameters["@ID"].Value = 1; into the code. Once I done that I will post query result, asap.

Comment: I am not getting errors when I run the program but it is not working correctly. I changed from @ID to @QTY in WHERE. here is the query result...                                              ID      FIRSTNAME     LASTNAME QTY
--      ---------     -------- ----
19      testa         testb    6
15      testc         testd    2
18      teste         testf    12

Comment: @Disco In your updated code you are trying to do a `SET` in a `SELECT` statement, you can't do that, you have to do that in an `UPDATE` statement. Based on the other things you have tried, etc. I would recommend going back to how you were doing it originally (although I would advise using either my code or some of the other code posted here). The 1 thing you should change is where you are comparing ID=1, change those lines (both your select and your update) to ID=19. You should get the correct results for that case now. You can further experiment with ID=15 and ID=18. All of those should work.

Comment: Pstrjds, Thank you so much for your spare time on helping me out. Taking somebody's free time, such as yourself, should be acknowledged throughout the IT forums like Stackflow. Before this post is closed. Does it matter, for instance, how WHERE ID =19 is coded in the professional environment. Is it something that the developer can get away with?

Comment: In a more professionaly environment you would probably want to use the paramaterized queries (part of the reason is because of SQL injection attacks, they help prevent some of those cases), but it really depends on what you are doing. I tend to use parameterized queries and in some cases stored procedures on the server, but again it depends what I am doing. I don't know that there really is a general rule that says you should always do X. There are times that I simply get an ID from a combo box and build my `SELECT` in a similar fashion to yours.

Comment: Your question about coding WHERE ID=19 or if you should do it a different way is a good question to ask at: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 5):

The problem is that you don't check for the case where `ret == -1`. Changing your second if-statement to `if(ret < 1)` should fix your issue.

Also, directly after the line `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();` add `ret--;` to sync the `ret` variable with the value that is now in the database.

Comment: joshperry - I am afraid it doesn't solve the problem. Message I am receiving constantly "Reorder: Remaining Stock: 1". Shouldn't the else statement reduced the stock level when btQty is clicked? If possible what is alternative solution?

Comment: @user Your update query is reducing your stock. The else is just displaying. You need to attach with a debugger and look at the return value from your `ExecuteScalar` call. Based on your code, if that is returning an empty string then you are setting ret to -1. When ret is -1, your original code is setting labels to "-2". Without your DB and other code, its hard to diagnose beyond that. I am assuming that you are getting back an empty string, why you are getting an empty string is a different story and that is where the debugger comes in.

Answer (score 3):

I think this is your problem - you make `ret - 1` while processing and then

```
txtQty.Text = "Remaining stocks: " + (ret - 1).ToString();
lbqty.Text = "Remaining stocks: " + (ret - 1).ToString();
```

that shows one less item. Try making it:

```
txtQty.Text = "Remaining stocks: " + ret.ToString();
lbqty.Text = "Remaining stocks: " + ret.ToString();
```

Comment: Migol - it doesn't work. Stock level does not get reduced. But output message know says -1. Why doesn't the stock level gets reduced?

Answer (score 1):

Your application flow should be as following;

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SqlConnection c = new SqlConnection("Data Source=.; Integrated Security=SSPI; Initial Catalog=FA");


        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
        cmd.Connection = c;
        c.Open();

        // get remaining stocks
        cmd.CommandText = "SELECT Qty from TEST WHERE Id=1";
        int ret = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString());

        if (ret == 0)
        {
            Label1.Text = "Not enough stocks.";
        }
        else 
        {
            cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE TEST SET Qty = Qty-1 WHERE Id=1";
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

            if (ret == 2)
            {
                Label1.Text = "Re-order. Remaining stocks: 1";
            }
            else
            {
                Label1.Text = "Remaining stocks: " + (ret-1).ToString();
            }
        }


        c.Close();
    }
```

Comment: Kadir - Pls could you have a look at my first posting. I used your code but it is not working as it should be.

Comment: Kadir- I am sorry to say it is not working as it should be. I have addition comments above to joshperry.

Answer (score 0):

The fist thing i can see is that this in not right

```
 if (ret == 1)
        {
            lbqty.Text = "Re-order. Remaining stocks: 1";
            dgUpdate();
        }
        else
```

should be

```
 if (ret - 1  == 1)
        {
            lbqty.Text = "Re-order. Remaining stocks: 1";
            dgUpdate();
        }
        else
```

because when the value you read is 1 and you decrease it its 0.